# ocaml problems with nested functions and variables

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I am trying to make function restric that would restrict  a table's values according to columns that have value [value]. My idea is to make a list consisting of trues and falses for the column that satisfy condition column and value parameters. Later on recursive match would chose the columns and a listmaker function would make a new column according to true falses list.

When it comes to storing in ocaml nested variables, let...in scoping I am very confused. What is wrong with the code bellow?

```
let rec restrict (column, value, aTable) = match aTable with
    name,[]->[]
  |name,(col,vals)::rest->if col=column
      then (col,auxListMaker(vals,trueFalseList))::restrict (column,value.(name,rest))
      else restrict (column,value.(name,rest))

let rec auxTrueFalser (column, value, aTable) = match aTable with 
    name,[]->[]
  |name,(col,vals)::rest-> if column=col 
      then (if List.hd vals = value 
            then true::aux1(column,value,(name,[(col,List.tl vals)]))
            else false::aux1(column,value,(name,[(col,List.tl vals)])))
      else aux1(column,value,(name,rest)) 
in 

let trueFalseList =  auxTrueFalser (column, value, aTable) in

let rec auxListMaker (vals, trueFalseList) = match vals with
    []->[]
  |h::t -> if List.hd trueFalseList
      then h::auxListMaker(t,List.tl trueFalseList)
      else auxListMaker(t,List.tl trueFalseList)
in
```

Answer (score 3):

The main thing to realize is that there are two uses of `let`. The first form is used to define the values in a module, and must appear at the outermost level of a module. It looks like this:

```
let name = expression
```

As a handy syntax, you can define a function at the outermost level like this:

```
let name arg = expression
```

The other form of `let` can appear anywhere, and is used to define a local variable. It looks like this:

```
let name = expression1 in expression2
```

This establishes `name` as a local variable with the value given by `expression1`. The scope of the name (where it can be used) is `expression2`.

Again, as a handy syntax, you can define a local function like this:

```
let name arg = expression1 in expression2
```

It looks to me like `auxListMaker` and `auxTrueFlser` are supposed to be local functions defined inside `restrict`. And `trueFalseList` is supposed to be a local (non-function) value. So the form of `restrict` would be something like this:

```
let rec restrict (column, value, aTable) =

    let auxTrueFalser (column, value, aTable) =
        ...
    in

    let auListMaker (vals, trueFalseList) =
        ...
    in

    let trueFalseList = auxTrueFalser (column, value, aTable) in

    ... (* body of restrict *)
```

In this layout `restrict` is defined at the top level (so just with `let`, no `in`). The other names are local variables (values and functions), and so are defined with `let ... in`.

Also note that you must define a name before using it. In your code the name `auxListMaker` is used before being defined. In the above layout, the order is OK.

**Update**

Answers to further questions.

The scope of the first form of `let` (with no `in`) is the rest of the module. For the common case of a simple .ml source file, this means the rest of the file.

Yes, the `restrict` function shown in the above schematic layout will re-evaluate the value for `trueFaleList` at every recursive call.

If you're working at a terminal that OCaml knows about, it underlines the place where it thinks you have a syntax error. The syntax of the first few lines of the schematic layout above is clearly OK. You'll have to show your code (or the smallest self-contained subset that shows the problem) and the specific error message you got.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation! 

1st question that arises is: what is the scope of let if after "in" one omits expression2? 

2nd question I have is: would the restrict evaluate the trueFalseList  every time it is called recursively? 

The form you showed still gives syntax error. The let of the auxTrueFalser is underlined. What is the reason?

Comment: The rest of the code I have written works well without this part. I write and execute the code here: https://try.ocamlpro.com/fun-demo/tryocaml_index.html#path%3Ddemo